# How to insert particular value based on some matches inside an object

Tags: javascript, json

I have two objects with the following structure:

```js
var one = { 
    '26-34-1'  : 100,
    '26-34-84' : 101
};

var two = [ 
    { 
        from : { id: '34', sid: '26' },
        to   : { id: '1',  sid: '26' } 
    },
    { 
        from : { id: '34', sid: '26' },
        to   : { id: '84', sid: '26' } 
    }
];
```

The keys in `one` *(eg. 26-34-1)* identify an object in `two` in the format:
`from.sid` - `from.id` - `to.id`

What I need to do is insert the value from `one` into `two` if the *key* in `one` matches.  Resulting in:

```js
var two = [ 
    { 
        from  : { id: '34', sid: '26' },
        to    : { id: '1',  sid: '26' },
        oneid : { id: 100 }
    },
    { 
        from  : { id: '34', sid: '26' },
        to    : { id: '84', sid: '26' },
        oneid : { id: 101 } 
    }
];
```

I can't seem to figure it out, I think it's done with *"mapping"* but wasn't able to map `from.sid`, `from.id` and `to.id`.  Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: seems straightforward. one[two[0].from.sid + "-" + two[0].from.id + "-"+two[0].to.id] is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: As I understand from another answer it's not what TS was asking about, my in case he doesn't have `two` yet next code will do what's needed.

```
for (var key in one) {
  var values = key.split('-');
  var object = {
    from: {
      id: values[1],
      sid: values[0]
    },
    to: {
      id: values[2],
      sid: values[0]
    },
    oneid: {
      id: one[key]
    }
  };

  two.push(object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
two.forEach(function(o){
    var key = [o.from.sid, o.from.id, o.to.id].join('-');
    if(key in one) o.oneid = { id: one[key] };
});
```

- [Javascript `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) *(for old browsers)*

Comment: As I understood he needs to do it the opposite way

Comment: *"What I need to do is insert value from one to two"* - if you are unsure perhaps you should ask for clarification before down voting other answers :/  what you've done creates a new object which adds an unnecessary overhead if this is just a simplified example from a more complex structure...

Comment: I'll give you a plus.

Comment: But before you edited the question it was saying "What I need to do is insert value from one to two in following way". So I decided he doesn't have array ```two``` yet.

Comment: What "way"? the sentence does't make sense in the context of the second code block - given the first block of code details an ***existing*** variable, the inference is that he wants to modify that same instance.  If it suggests anything else then it seems more likely to be a mistranslation as the post was in relatively broken English?  (I'm also looking at the user's only other question - where he arrived at that structure in the first place)

Comment: I did put a caveat in my edit description anyway - so I'm happy to be proven wrong if he clarifies ;)